# sql-server-2008 windows authentication problems

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

i  have a timeclock database setup on a windows 2008 server, sql server. it has been working for MONTHS. today all of a sudden it seems like some peoples' logins is working and some peoples' login is not working. sql authentication works fine however the windows authentication is not working. i checked the log files and it seems like sql server 2008 is just not liking the passwords! does anyone know what could be going on here?

i checked the windows server error log. here is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-admin/Clock-Skew.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just a wild guess..

But your time is out.. So your Kerberos timestamps are out of sync, effectively shutting down your domain????
Did you just have a DayLight-Savings???

Comment: @arenstar how do we correct it if it's daylight savings?

Comment: Im a unix guy, but familiar with Kerberos..

Basically.. Set your clock to UTC and enable the daylight savings

I probably would run NTP on your servers too.. To keep them in sync outside of the actual host clock..

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914387#appliesto    You havent done your Updates im guessing :D

Comment: @arenstar i dont  know if this is the right answer since even after the time change it worked but stopped working like after 12 hours or something like that

Comment: Im feeling pretty confident that im right.. :D

But let me know if im wrong.. i would like to know

Comment: arenstar thank u very much for your help but the clients times are fine. they are set correctly! is there something about the way that they are set up could be changed?

Comment: @arenstar thank u very much for your help but the clients times are fine. they are set correctly! is there something about the way that they are set up could be changed?

Comment: To be honest, google is more helpful than me with this. Try 'time skew kerberos windows domain'... See what comes up. Im on my iphone now

Answer (score 1):

Check the windows security event log on the domain controllers.  It could be consistency between the domain controllers.   Did some of the servers time sync fall out of place due to daylight savings yesterday?

Comment: @arenstar how do we correct it if it's daylight savings?

Comment: how would i know that it is daylight problem

Comment: the easiest method would be from your control panel under calendar/time.  or by double clicking the time on your system tray.

Comment: and then what? the time is the same as everyone else's